# Python, Regular Expression: How to remove letter.letter(a.b) from string?

Tags: python, regex

How can I remove combination of letter-dot-letter (example F.B) from string in python ? I tried using regex:

```
abre = re.sub(r"\b\w+\.\w+@",'',abre)
```

but it does not remove these sequences it just prints me the same unchanged string. I also tried removing all dots and then remove words smaller than 2 letters, but in that case I loose real words.

What I have: C.P.A. Certification Program, Accounting

What I want to get: Certification Program, Accounting

The length of the sequence is not always known and the letters are also unknown.

Comment: What went wrong with your regex? What do you mean by "does not work"? `F.B` does not contain `@`, you can't expect your pattern to match the string.

Comment: *"words smaller than 1 letter"*: seems you are hunting ghosts.

Comment: Well you have the + quantifier after the \w, so it is going to match between 1 and an infinite amount of letters/numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does not remove these sequences it just prints me the same unchanged string

Comment: Some examples of inputs and desired outputs showing exactly what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: @glibud updated my question with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to remove words that consist of dot-separated uppercase letters.

Use

```
abre = re.sub(r"\b(?:[A-Z]\.)+(?!\w)",'',abre)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/92CUV5/1). To also remove a trailing whitespace, you may add `\s*` at the end. If there must be at least two letters, replace `+` with `{2,}`.

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:[A-Z]\.)+` - one or more sequences of

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `\.`  -a dot
- `(?!\w)` - not followed with a word char

Comment: Note I used `(?!\w)` because a `\.\b` would match a dot only if it is followed with a word char. `(?!\w)` makes an unambiguous word boundary. Depending on the input, you may even omit it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace` :

```
>>> string="rgoa.bwtg.rgqra.bergeg"
>>> string.replace("a.b", "")
'rgowtg.rgqrergeg'
```

Comment: But it's not always a.b, it can be any letters.